# Usage of deployment.toml in wso2 apim 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, toml

I want to deploy a gateway-worker profile for WSO2 APIM 3.0.0. As i understand, the new deployment.toml file is used to override all configuration files when the instance is started.

- Is the shared DB required for a deployment of a gateway instance only, because toml overidding failed if I remove this database ? I was thinking that gateway doesn't required any database.
- Why this toml file doesn't remove all not necessary datasources in master-datasources.xml, all datasources are still active with h2 even if they are not describe in the toml file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

shared DB is required for the gateway in tenancy mode. Hence it is a required data source. 
Default APIM distribution required both AM DB and Shared DB, hence only those data sources are defined in the TOML file. In profiles, some data sources can be removed. In order to configure the profile, you need to run the profile optimization tool[1]. Optimization tool will generate profile-specific TOML configuration with minimum required configuration.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/SetupAndInstall/DeployingWSO2APIManager/DistributedDeployment/product-profiles/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to deploy the gateway without any database if we don't need multi tenancy ? When I remove the sharedDB datasource in the TOML file it fails at startup.

Comment: You can keep the default configurations(Will use the internal H2 database).